# SSH connection to an OpenShift virtual machine not working

Tags: ssh, openshift, virtualization

I have created a virtual machine using RedHat OpenShift virtualization, but I am unable to connect to it using SSH.

My virtual machine pod is running and I am able to able to access the pod terminal from the webconsole. I followed the instructions given in [this page](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/virt/virtual_machines/virt-accessing-vm-consoles.html) to create the ssh service.

```sh
[root@api.ocpcluster-m1.cp.mydomain.com ~]# oc get pods
NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
virt-launcher-fedora-clumsy-lamprey1-7rdgm   1/1     Running   0          22d

[root@api.ocpcluster-m1.cp.mydomain.com ~]# oc get svc
NAME            TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
fedora-vm-ssh   NodePort   172.30.84.81   <none>        22:31016/TCP   22d

[root@api.ocpcluster-m1.cp.mydomain.com ~]# ssh root@10.17.55.207 -p 31016
ssh: connect to host 10.17.55.207 port 31016: No route to host
[root@api.ocpcluster-m1.cp.mydomain.com ~]#
```

`10.17.55.207` is the IP of one of the nodes.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `ssh root@10.17.55.207 -p 31016` are you sure that you have a right user ? Did you set `root` password during vm bootstrap ?

Comment: root was there already , I tried adding a user from the pod terminal but I am unable set password it says unknown command
sh-4.4# passwd
sh: passwd: command not found
sh-4.4# 

How can I set the password for the user I created?

Comment: The 10.17.55.207 node is running locally as some KVM virtual machine on your machine/laptop ? 10.0.0.0/8 is a private address range so unless your machine from which you trying to connect is not in same network you won't be able to connect. Try to `ping -c 3 10.17.55.207`. Is it working from machine you are trying to ssh to node where openshift vm is running ?

Comment: I am connecting from the infra node
[root@api.ocpcluster-m1.cp.mydomain.com ~]# ping -c 3 10.17.55.207
PING 10.17.55.207 (10.17.55.207) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.17.55.207: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.482 ms
64 bytes from 10.17.55.207: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.225 ms
64 bytes from 10.17.55.207: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.222 ms

--- 10.17.55.207 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 28ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.222/0.309/0.482/0.123 ms
[root@api.ocpcluster-m1.cp.mydomain.com ~]#

Comment: I am able to ping the worker node ip from my infra node

Comment: 10.17.55.207 is the IP of one of the worker node.

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/virt/virtual_machines/virt-accessing-vm-consoles.html
the above page says
Log in to the VMI via SSH. Use the ipAddress of any of the cluster nodes and the port that you found in the previous step:
$ ssh username@<node_IP_address> -p 32551

Comment: Ok, it seems that you did everything right, but I spot one Prerequisite at https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/virt/virtual_machines/virt-accessing-vm-consoles.html#virt-accessing-vmi-ssh_virt-accessing-vm-consoles, look at `The VMI you want to access must be connected to the default pod network by using the masquerade binding method.` Look at https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/virt/virtual_machines/vm_networking/virt-using-the-default-pod-network-with-virt.html#virt-configuring-masquerade-mode-cli_virt-using-the-default-pod-network-with-virt

Comment: Yes, I verified that, it is using masquerade binding.

here is the snippet from my vm.yaml
        devices:
          disks:
            - bootOrder: 1
              disk:
                bus: virtio
              name: fedora-clumsy-lamprey1
            - disk:
                bus: virtio
              name: cloudinitdisk
          interfaces:
             - masquerade: {}
               name: default
          networkInterfaceMultiqueue: true
          rng: {}

however, there is no ports set ,could that be the reason why the connections are not allowed?

Comment: If you could log into VM-s web console, than try to run `ss -plnt | grep 22` or `netstat -plnt | grep 22` if you see `22` at your VM you trying to ssh, then it should works. If not, I will try to set `- port: 22` and redeploy VM.